# Joi Validation of array items field based on values in objects in another array

Tags: hapi.js, joi

I have a scenario where i want to validate a json object using Joi like below

```
"a" : [{
id: "abc",
color: "red"
},
{
id: "def",
color: "blue"
},
{
id: "ghc",
color: "green"
}],
b:[{
userid: ["ghc","ijk"],
color: "green"
},
{
userid: ["ghc","abc"],
color: "green"
},{
userid: ["def"],
color: "green"
},{
userid: ["ghc","ijk"],
color: "green"
}]

}
```

i want to validate "b.userid" which is array of strings to have values from "a.id" which is an array of object with id as a property inside.

i was able to validate if b.userid is a simple string rather than a array of strings with the following Joi schema as below successfully

```
Joi.object().keys({
  a: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
    id: Joi.string().required(),
    color: Joi.string()
  })),
  b: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
      userid: Joi.string().valid(Joi.ref('....a',{
                        in: true,
                        adjust: (a) => a.map(aa => aa.id)
        })),
    color: Joi.string()
  }))
})
```

but when i try with the userid being an array of strings with the modified Joi schema below,

```
Joi.object().keys({
  a: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
    id: Joi.string().required(),
    color: Joi.string()
  })),
  b: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
      userid: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid(Joi.ref('....a',{
                        in: true,
                        adjust: (a) => a.map(aa => aa.id)
        }))),
    color: Joi.string()
  }))
})
```

i get the following error :

**Not a valid joi Schema**

Can someone help me where am i getting it wrong. how do i use Joi.ref correctly in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

When you made it into an array, you changed the level in which `a` is, so it's not a valid ref.

Just add one more dot to the key or use the slash to search from root, *e.g.*, `'.....a'` or `'/a'`